# Restrict OAuth2 token to specific models/views in Django

Tags: django, api, rest, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I'm developing my first more than trivial API-interface in Django with Django Rest Framework. I'm trying to create a web service which hosts high-score tables for my games. Games will then post and retrieve their high-scores via http-requests through the API.

At the moment my model structure looks something like this:

- Game

  - Highscoretable

    - HighscoreEntry

Now since the service will handle scores of multiple different games, I'd like to give a separate oauth2 token for each game and restrict the api-permissions to that game. I managed to setup the oauth2 authentication with this guide: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication

However, at the moment it seems to give access to whole API. Next I checked http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions , where there there is mention that to restrict the permissions to subset functionality I need a custom permission classes.

Based on this information I tried googling examples about how to do this with oauth2. In the same page there was an example of a custom class. However, I have no idea how to apply it to oauth2. Can I somehow set a specific access_token to my Game model so that when the request comes, I can compare requester's token to Game's own token? If so how?

tl;dr; How to create a custom permission classes for models with unique oauth2 tokens? So that each token gives permissions to its corresponding model.

Answer (score 0):

In order to control the access tokens permissions, you should use scope. The idea of the access token scope is to give rights to defined set of operations, resources, whatever (it's up to you) based on the access token scope. In your case, you should provide different scopes for different games. Note that the scope itself does not restrict the user to some endpoints, services, etc. How the scope restrictions are applied depends on OAuth20 provider.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I checked the django-oauth2-provider's documentation but couldn't find any examples of how to use scoping in practice.

Comment: You can check ApiFest project - http://apifest.com. It is open-source, pure Java - https://github.com/apifest. Using the documentation, you can easily start the server and try it out. It supports scopes.